# jQuery: How can I alter SOME html but keep the rest?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I want to load a page from my server, modify the links (anchors) but keep the rest of the HTML the same. Is this possible with jQuery?

Example:

I want this code...

```
<div>
    text 1<a href="link1.html">link 1</a><br/>
    text 2<a href="link2.html">link 2</a><br/>
    text 3<a href="link3.html">link 3</a><br/>
</div>
```

...to become this code...

```
<div>
    text 1<a href="link4.html">link 1</a><br/>
    text 2<a href="link5.html">link 2</a><br/>
    text 3<a href="link6.html">link 3</a><br/>
</div>
```

I want the WHOLE code, including the DIVs.

Is this possible with jQuery? Please help! Thanks in advance. :)

Edit: Each page I load will be different. I want to pull in the full HTML, change the anchor HREFs, then return the results. I can't use a template because each page will be different.

Comment: This is possible with jQuery, follow a few tutorial and you'll achieve it easily.

Comment: Can you show us the jQuery that is 'getting' the html?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the HREF value of an anchor tag, just use the `attr`*<sup>[[API Ref]](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)</sup>* method:

```
$('a[href="link1.html"]').attr('href', 'link4.html');
$('a[href="link2.html"]').attr('href', 'link5.html');
$('a[href="link3.html"]').attr('href', 'link6.html');
```

This code can be run on static HTML or HTML that was loaded dynamically. It makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using some type of templating functionality to accomplish this if you are using jQuery.

[Here is an old version](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) of a templating engine the jQuery team was considering using. [Here is some updated information](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) on why it was deprecated and what the current progress is on creating a new version.

There are other templating methods out there to accomplish this as well. You can also do it manually via DOM manipulation as other people are recommending.

Answer (score 0):

**You can modify an element's attributes using the .attr()** method with jQuery. The first value is the attribute that you want to modify, and the second value is it's new value.

```
$('a').attr('href','yourlinkhere.html');
```

...the above will modify all links to point to "yourlinkhere.html". You can get more specific as to what you want to edit by iterating through all the links like this:

```
$("a").each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('href','link'+index+'.html');
});
```

...or by targeting specific links like so:

```
$("a[href=link1.html]").attr('href', 'yourlinkhere.html');
```

...the **problem with an approach like this though, is that you will replace all instances that point to that page**. Chances are you want to add an Id to your links, and target them like so:

```
$("a#specificLinksId").attr('href', 'yourlinkhere.html');
```

...or by class like this: